# Transferring Databinding setting Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have a CollectionView of Class Objects and a button that retrieves SelectedItem and opens ClassInfoPage. I was wondering if there's a way to apply the same bindingcontext of SelectedItem to ClassInfoPage. My goal is for ClassInfoPage to use the same Class object as SelectedItem, without having to retrieve the object from SelectedItem, Modify it in ClassInfoPage, and put it back into its ObservableCollection. Thanks in advance

**CollectionView xaml**

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Classes}" x:Name="ClassesCollectionView" SelectionMode="Single" HeightRequest="0">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <FlexLayout Direction="Row" AlignItems="Center" JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly" HeightRequest="35">
                            <Label Text="{Binding ClassName}" FontSize="Micro" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding ClassStatus}" FontSize="Micro"/>
                            <DatePicker Date="{Binding ClassStartDate}" FontSize="Micro"/>
                            <DatePicker Date="{Binding ClassEndDate}" FontSize="Micro"/>
                        </FlexLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

my code so far in the ClassInfoButton click event

```
private async void ClassInfoButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FlexLayout selectedClass = ClassesCollectionView.SelectedItem as FlexLayout;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ClassInfoPage());
        }
```

ClassInfoPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TermManager.ClassInfoPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <FlexLayout AlignItems="Center" Direction="Row" JustifyContent="SpaceBetween">
            <DatePicker Date="{Binding ClassStartDate}"/>
            <Editor Text="{Binding ClassName}"/>
            <DatePicker Date="{Binding ClassEndDate}"/>
        </FlexLayout>
            <Editor Text="{Binding ClassNotes}"/>
            <Editor Text="{Binding ClassTeacherName}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to cast your `SelectedItem` as `MyClass` (whatever that is), not `FlexLayout`, and then pass it to `ClassInfoPage`

```
private async void ClassInfoButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyClass selectedClass = ClassesCollectionView.SelectedItem as MyClass;
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ClassInfoPage(selectedClass));
}
```

then in `ClassInfoPage`

```
public ClassInfoPage(MyClass data) 
{
  this.BindingContext = data;
}
```

C# objects are passed by reference, so any change you make to the object in `ClassInfoPage` should be reflected in your first page, although you might need to refresh your UI (or use `INotifyPropertyChanged`) to see it